# Change to dataset breaks form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

WinForm, VB.Net, VS 2017

I used the dataset wizard to create a dataset. I dragged the dataset to a new form to populate a grid. I did another drag of the detail fields. The form works OK.  I then edited the dataset and removed a field from the middle of the record. When I load the form no records are bound.

I added `MyApplication_UnhandledException` but it did not fire either.

Any clues to what might be wrong? Looks like a low-level bug to me.

---

I was able to reproduce the bug in VS 15.4.2

```
0 new Winform VB.Net
0 Add/Configure Dataset via wizard
0 add table using defaults
0 drag fields to create grid on form
0 drag fields to create detail fields
0 set as startup form
0 run - check to see navigator, grid and details function
0 edit added table - remove field using the query designer (not the first of last field - guess)
0 run - nothing works
```

Comment: Presumably there is a call to the `Fill` method of a table adapter in the `Load` event handler of the form.  Wrap that in a `Try...Catch` block and see if it detects something.  Exceptions thrown in the `Load` event handler get in 64-bit apps and I'm not sure whether the `UnhandledException` event can catch them either.

Comment: That said, a column would have been created in your `DataGridView` for that `DataColumn` column that has since been removed as well as a `TextBox` or some other control for the details.  Did you delete them in the designer?  If not then they will still be trying to bind to that missing `DataColumn` and that's what will fail.  Those controls won't be updated automatically just because you changed the `DataSet`.

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a clean environment using a simple data table. If you could reproduce the problem and you couldn't find the answer yourself, then share reproduction steps here.

Comment: Load doesn't fire so Fill is not called. The designer does populate the form but that's it. I was able to reproduce: new WinForm, add table to data set, drag gird to form, drag details to form, set as startup form, runs OK, edit table added and remove a field (from middle?), on run controls display but no data. I see a new version 15.4.2 is available I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: Added steps to reproduce in latest VS 2017. I know the designer code may need tweaking to remove unused controls but we should be getting an error, not a form the loads but is dysfunctional.